# Prove that $f*g$ is differentiable at $0$ without product rule.

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

Suppose that $f : R → R$ and $g : R → R$ are continuous functions satisfying (i) $f(0) = 0$, (ii) $f'(0)=3$, and (iii) $g(0) = 2$. Prove that $f*g$ is differentiable at $0$, and find $(f*g)'(0)$.
Note: The product rule for derivatives cannot be used for this problem, since $g$ may not
be differentiable at $0$. You must use the definition of derivative.

So, I know we can define that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-0}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$. No clue where to go, since we can't know if g is differentiable at $0$, but can we prove it, or do we have to go a different route? Any pointers would be great, thanks!

I just need to explicitly NOT use product rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by definition:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)g(x)-f(0)g(0)}{x-0}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)g(x)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\cdot g(0)\\
&=f'(0)\cdot g(0).
\end{align*}